# PowerShell: suppress Write-Progress output

Tags: powershell, redirect, progress

I have a PowerShell script that calls a CmdLet which in turn reports its progress using Write-Progress, and I would like to hide the progress bar.
In is it possible to suppress or redirect the output of the Write-Progress CmdLet?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try setting this preference variable before calling the cmdlet that utilizes Write-Progress:

```
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
```

You may want to revert back to 'Continue' afterwards.

Comment: it doesn't work when you import module and module import issues Write-Progress

Comment: Must be a little more to it because it does suppress it in this case: $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; new-module -ScriptBlock { for ($i=0;$i -lt 100; $i += 5) { Write-Progress act stat -perc $i; Start-Sleep -milli 500 }} -pass | ipmo

Comment: Just to confirm Vladimir here - this preference doesn't turn off progress bars when import-module is used. Progress bars are great when using adhoc commands but in a logon script are a bit distracting

Comment: Is it possible the module is overriding the value of `$ProgressPreference`?

Comment: #lifesaver 

for my scenario where i want to suppress the Get-ComputerInfo message, it worked as charm.